# JAXB, custom marshalling of relationships

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jaxb

I have an API which allows a third party to interact with my database via XML files which represent my java domains.

I use JAXB to define the xsd as well as marshal/un-marshal between my POJO and the XML.

The problem I face is how to support the equivalent of a hibernate lazy load. i.e. Only marshal objects recursively upon a certain condition. The condition I have in mind is something like what RequestFactory uses which is a .with(...) where the user can specify exactly which part of the object graph to return.

Consider the case where a "Person" has an "Image" in another table. When using the API and requests a "Person" I want to be able to specify .with(Image) or something equivalent, otherwise every use case gets penalised having to carry this image which 

(a) is not required 

(b) Has an unnecessary database hit. 

I have 100+ tables and the permutations are too complex to code specialised POJO's.

How do I satisfy the above requirement using JAXB or any other free library.

Comment: Why not working with inheritance. You can create Person object, and PersonWithmage extends Person. While Parent has no requirments, child may have additional fields required.

Comment: I would do that  if it was just 10 or so cases, but the sheer number of permutations to meet any possible third party requirement is not manageable.

Comment: You can do it via some reflection, implementing a with() method (an interface used by each serializable to xml object) that parse the object via reflection to match the parameters/mappings passed to with() and finally return members of given object by mapping

Comment: If I understand this correctly it means that I would handle the marshalling manually and pretty much doing away with JAXB? I had started designing a manual solution but was hoping to avoid this.

Comment: You can also create at runtime JAXB objects ;)

Comment: That sounds promising although I suspect it involves custom coding for each case.... I will investigate. Thanks.

Comment: A lot of searching and I still havent found something suitable. If you can send me a link Id be very interested.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible simple solutions (assuming you use JPA entities with JAXB annotations but works as well with simple POJOs):

- enrich each entity with some copying method - i.e. 'copyForExport'
- this method creates unmanaged copy of an entity without values unwanted for the export
- marshal your copy

Example:

```
@Entity
@XmlType
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SampleEntity {
    @Id private long id;
    @Column private String meaningful;
    @Column private String something1;
    @OneToMany private List<Something> something2;

    SampleEntity copyForExport() {
        SampleEntity copy = new SampleEntity();
        copy.id = id;
        copy.meaningful = meaningful;
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Comment: He don't want to create an entity for all the object to be serialized, pointed out in comments.

Comment: So you can take away JPA annotations if you don't like them :)

Comment: But in that way you stell need to create a class and a method manually for all instances you want to serialize.

Comment: There are POJOs already - so it's enough to enrich them with 1 additional method.

Comment: " have 100+ tables and the permutations are too complex to code specialised POJO's.", i already proposed  your solution in comments.

Comment: All entities (=POJOs) can be generated automatically from DB (i.e. with NetBeans) and enriched with demonstrated method.

Comment: I like this idea. I have to just be careful as this chains deeper down the object graph but I dont foresee a problem. Will try it tomorrow and update the post. Thanks!

Comment: I see I misunderstood Yuri's response earlier who indeed proposed something similar. My response to that was that JAXB would be done away with. From this example its clear to me that JAXB remains and is useful for both creating the xsd and marshaling the copy.

Comment: In that case this is a possible good solution, and doesn't even need reflection because your method return the JAXB object. This can also being "pefected" by adding an interface, so you may know  which instances use the "export" contract. The bad is that the marshalled copy will expose get/set methods for accessing unset properties wich may result in NPE.

Comment: My intention is to have a base class for relevant domains which handles what it can via reflection. I will thrash it out tomorrow and hopefully post the result. Up votes to you both.